# Option `samples y` in scope doesn't work

Tags: pgfplots, scoping

Appearantly I don't understand how `scope` works.

The following compiles fine:

```
\begin{scope}[samples=20,domain=0:12]
\addplot3[samples y=0] plot (x, x, -x*x);
\end{scope}
```

but the following gives the error *Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/samples y'*:

```
\begin{scope}[samples=20,samples y=0,domain=0:12]
\addplot3 plot (x, x, -x*x);
\end{scope}
```

How can I use the `samples y` option in the scope?

**Edit:** This is a MWE that does not work, because `samples y` is in the `scope`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
\addplot3[domain=0:1, y domain=0:1, surf] plot (x, y, {x*y});
\begin{scope}[domain=0:1,samples y=0]
\addplot3 plot (x, x, 0);
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `samples y` is a pgfplots option. But a scope evaluates its option in TikZ key family.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.

Comment: @percusse, Do you know of some way to put `samples y` into a scope to prevent me from repeating this option for a large amount of similar `addplot3`'s?

Comment: Use the full key: `/pgfplots/samples y=0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pgfplots options, such as `samples y`, cannot go directly in a `scope` like Tikz options can, like

```
\begin{scope}[samples y=0]
```

but have to be prefixed by `/pgfplots/` like

```
\begin{scope}[/pgfplots/samples y=0]
```

*[Credit goes to user **esdd** who solved answered me in the comment]*